# Use date-related query to count number of outstanding jobs

Tags: sql, t-sql

Given the below image:

[image]

How do I query the left table to produce something like the right table?
The criteria is: for a given date, count the number of jobs that have been submitted up to that given data that haven't been closed yet (i.e. still pending)

So looking at the dates in the above table:

On 18/6/18, a single job was pending - ID 2

On 19/6/18, three jobs pending - ID 3,4,5

On 20/6/18, two jobs pending - ID 4,5

On 21/6/18, two jobs pending - ID 5,7

On 22/6/18, one job pending - ID 7

The below is an incorrect solution that I attempted:

```
SELECT opendate, count(*)
FROM t
WHERE opendate < closedate
GROUP BY opendate
```

It's incorrect because for a given date, say 20/6/18, it won't count the open jobs from previous dates like 19/6/18, of which there are two.

Comment: What is the result when you execute the query? I'm confused on what you are trying to get because you say `I know the below is incorrect`, but then you say `It's correct because for a given date...`

Comment: Sorry, typo. I'm trying to get the table on the right in the image.

Comment: What is the criteria for producing the `pending` column?

Comment: Why is there a "pending" case on the 18th? Seems that both cases on the 18th were already closed and are thus not "pending". I would assume that only 22nd has one pending case, other dates should be zero.

Comment: I have added some details on the criteria for the "pending" column that I desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need distinct open dates and join to the table before the grouping:

```
SELECT tt.opendate, count(*) pending
FROM (
  select distinct opendate 
  from t
) tt inner join  t
on tt.opendate >= t.opendate and tt.opendate < t.closedate
GROUP BY tt.opendate
```